# calculate subtotal in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a vue js project that it's like a cart.
I want to calculate subtotal of each row of product.

my html code:

```
<div id="app">
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>subtotal</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
        <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
        <td><input type="number" v-model="product.quantity"></td>
        <td>{{ product.subtotal }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and my js code is:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        products: [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "first",
                "price": 151,
                "quantity": 0,
                "subtotal": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "second",
                "price": 152,
                "quantity": 0,
                "subtotal": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "another record",
                "price": 0,
                "quantity": 0,
                "subtotal": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "hello",
                "price": 0,
                "quantity": 0,
                "subtotal": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "world",
                "price": 0,
                "quantity": 0,
                "subtotal": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    computed:{
        'product.subtotal': function(){
            return product.quantity * product.price;
        }
    }
});
```

how can I calculate subtotal for any product by changing the quantity?
I want to save calculated subtotal to product.subtotal property.

here is jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/s38wLk49/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong (well, incomplete):
Wouldn't changing `{{ product.subtotal }}` to `{{ product.price * product.quantity }}` do it?

Since he wants to actually change the data, not just the display, this is what I tried and it worked for me:

```js
watch:{
  products:{
   handler:function(newval,oldval) {
      this.products.forEach(p => {
          p.subtotal = p.price * p.quantity;
      });
   }, deep:true
  }
}
```

Vue supports watching a property of an object, but afaik, it doesn't work with an *array* of objects (I could be wrong!).

Comment: Although this will not *store* the value. For that, I'd use a watcher and update the value that way. I'll work on a variant for that.

Comment: No, I must use product.subtotal, because I read it from database later

Comment: how does it look now?

Answer (score 1):

Write a method.it will give a perfect solution for this.

```
// replace your subtotal <td> with this below

<td>{{ productSubtotal(product.price, product.quantity) }}</td>

// under methods you should write that method to calculate subtotal

methods: {
  productSubtotal(price, quantity) {
    return price * quantity;
  }
}
```